# Speeding up Doctrine 2 ->merge()

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Table setup:

```
Group <-> Role <-> User
```

With `cascade={"all"}` set up on Group -> Role -> User

```
$g = new Group();
$g->setId(1); // Group with ~1000 roles/members
$em->merge($g); // Takes several minutes
```

As far as I can tell, it's recursing through all the cascading entities sending one query per entity (Role and User). How can I optimize this?

Comment: this is what `cascade={"all"}` does - why would you use cascading AND setting an id afterwards? could you elaborate a bit more what you're really trying to do?

Comment: I have a detached entity that I wish to manage. Calling merge on it returns a managed copy

Comment: Got it but why would you set the id then? If you don't change the id then there wouldn't be any need to cascade. I don't understand.

Comment: And generally if you have to persist/delete large amounts of objects relying on ORM isn't suggested performance-wise. Just use your own repository function with a custom DQL function.

Comment: I'm facing this issue in an import tool, where I need to write the changes to entities to database. The entities may or may not have changes or be newly created (compared with database state). How would I get the merge logic into the repository class?

Comment: I suggest not to use ORM for imports/exports or generally bulk updates. See [Doctrine Batch processing page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html) for details, too.